# str value to reference of variable name and assignment

Tags: python, variables, exec, eval, assign

I am making a CLI program. So I need the user to see that their parameters have changed. I then store a metadata file that shows their params pass vs params actually ran, amongst other info.

I want to be able to perform *hault-less Exception Handling*, where my program ensures that a deterministic set of variables' values each satisfy their minimal requirements.

So far, I have this:

```
def my_function(datasets, samples, columns, n_cks, cks_length, non_unique):
    exception_handling = [['datasets', 1], ['samples', 2], ['columns', 3], ['n_cks', 1], ['cks_length', 2], [non_unique, 0.01]]

    for param, minim_req in exception_handling:
        if not exec(param) >= minim_req:
            exec(param) = minim_req
            print("'" + str(param) + "' was too small...")
            print("'" + str(param) + "' = " + minim_req)
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Same error when trying `eval()`, instead of `exec()` in both places.

---

Having read into using `locals()`, I have stumbled here also.

Solution Approach 2 - using `locals()`:

```
def my_function(datasets, samples, columns, n_cks, cks_length, non_unique):
    #exception_handling = [['datasets', 1], ['samples', 2], ['columns', 3], ['n_cks', 1], ['cks_length', 2]]
    minim_req = {'datasets': 1, 'samples': 2, 'columns': 3, 'n_cks': 1, 'cks_length': 2, 'non_unique': 0.01}
    
    params = locals()
    print(params)
    
    for key, value in params:
        if not value >= minim_req[key]:
            params[key] = minim_req[key]
            print("'" + str(key) + "' was too small...")
            print("'" + str(key) + "' = " + minim_req[key])
```

Error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Please explain the bigger picture, I think you're approaching your problem the wrong way.

Comment: @BeChillerToo I want to ensure these parameters passed are at least a certain value. I already have exception handling to ensure their data-types and existence.

Comment: exec is used for equation. For ex- `r = 3`                           `a = "r = 0"`. `exec(a)`

Comment: It is a CLI program. So I need the user to see that their parameters have changed. I then store a metadata file that shows their params pass vs params actually ran, amongst other info.

Comment: Please send your full code. What are dataset etc

Comment: This shouldn't matter. I want a way to reference these variables to call upon for assignment of minimum requirements.

Answer (score 0):

if all your variables are int, try something like this:

```
for param, minim_req in exception_handling:
    length = exec(param)
    if length < minim_req:
        # Do something with 'length'
```

Comment: I get TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: One of them is a float :(

Comment: Yeah it's ok I think

Comment: `my_function(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0)` gets `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Answer (score 0):

```
datasets, samples, columns, n_cks, cks_length, non_unique = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0

params = [['datasets', datasets], ['samples', samples], ['columns', columns], ['n_cks', n_cks], ['cks_length', cks_length], ['non_unique', non_unique]]
minim_req = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0.01]

for (i, val), m in zip(enumerate(params), minim_req):
    if not val[1] >= m:
        params[i][1] = m
        print("'" + params[i][0] + "' was too small...")
        print("'" + params[i][0] + "' = " + str(m) + "\n")
        
datasets, samples, columns, n_cks, cks_length, non_unique = params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4], params[5]
print(datasets, samples, columns, n_cks, cks_length, non_unique)
>>> 1 2 3 1 2 0.01
```

The only issue here is this relies on a static/ fixed set of variable names; which suffices for me.